# Using ECC-based p12 Certificates BP256 in an Electron Application

Tags: node.js, electron, cryptography, rsa, elliptic-curve

I'm working on an Electron application where I need to establish an HTTPS connection using ECC-based p12 certificates. As I understand, nodejs already supports some curves, but I need specifically BP-256 (brainpool256) curve.

What should I do to use a bp256 ECC certificate to create a TLS connection.